# Combining queries with must and should for multi-match query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use multi-match query as below. For some fields I want all keywords to be found in the field but for some other fields at least 1 keyword should be found. According to that I thought to combine 2 multi-match queries using must and should.

```
 "from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "explain": true,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "type": "best_fields",
                  "query": "hp 301",
                  "fields": [                       
                     "MPN^9",
                     "SKU^8"             
                  ]
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {"multi_match": {
                  "type": "best_fields",
               "query": "hp 301",
               "fields": [
                    "Name.raw2^7.5",
                     "Name^7",
                     "Description^6"
                     ]
            }}
         ]
      }
   }
```

If I understand correctly MPN and SKU must only match when hp and 301, both are found in the fields but when I analyze the scoring, I see this below.

***Product has:***  "MPN": "CF 301 A"

**explanation for it:**

```
 "_explanation": {
               "value": 2.0636692,
               "description": "sum of:",
               "details": [
                  {
                     "value": 1.0522164,
                     "description": "max of:",
                     "details": [
                        {
                           "value": 1.0522164,
                           "description": "product of:",
                           "details": [
                              {
                                 "value": 2.1044328,
                                 "description": "sum of:",
                                 "details": [
                                    {
                                       "value": 2.1044328,
                                       "description": "weight(MPN:301 in 375) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                       "details": [
                                          {
                                             "value": 2.1044328,
                                             "description": "score(doc=375,freq=1.0), product of:",
                                             "details": [
                                                {
                                                   "value": 0.45506343,
                                                   "description": "queryWeight, product of:",
                                                   "details": [
                                                      {
                                                         "value": 9,
                                                         "description": "boost",
                                                         "details": []
                                                      },
                                                      {
                                                         "value": 9.248965,
                                                         "description": "idf(docFreq=2, maxDocs=11471)",
                                                         "details": []
                                                      },
                                                      {
                                                         "value": 0.0054668393,
                                                         "description": "queryNorm",
                                                         "details": []
                                                      }
                                                   ]
                                                },
```

Why does MPN returns a score if only 301 is in the MPN field? Does it not require "hp" exist in the field as well? If not, How can I make it exact match?

Answer (score 4):

With the multimatch queries the search term defaults to being parsed out into separate words, and if anyone of those words match the query as a whole would match. What you need to do to break this default behavior is add in an 'and' operator so it knows to only match if both terms are found.

```
"from": 0,
   "size": 10,
   "explain": true,
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "multi_match": {
                  "type": "best_fields",
                  "query": "hp 301",
                  "fields": [                       
                     "MPN^9",
                     "SKU^8"             
                  ],
                  "operator": "and"
               }
            }
         ],
         "should": [
            {"multi_match": {
                  "type": "best_fields",
               "query": "hp 301",
               "fields": [
                    "Name.raw2^7.5",
                     "Name^7",
                     "Description^6"
                     ]
            }}
         ]
      }
   }
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It is correct but I thought must is ensuring that. what is the sense of must above? Does it require SKU and MPN both to be matched at the same time?

Comment: now it dont get any results because it looks like that must and should queries working like "AND". so it expects results from both. Is it possible to say if either of them returns results?